# Lumen return relationship specified in request

Tags: rest, lumen

Usually I use Yii2 to build rest API's. Right now I'm trying to rebuild an API, that I already have in Yii2, with Lumen for studies pourposes.

For example: I have a Game model that has a relationship with other models like:

```
public function homeTeam() {}
public function awayTeam() {}
public function stadium() {}
....
```

In Yii I can make a request like: http://localhost:8000/game/15

to get the Game with ID 15. In Lumen I can do the same, that's ok.

In Yii, when I want to get the home team and away team fields in the same request I can make a request like: http://localhost:8000/game/15&expand=homeTeam,awayTeam

that you return something like:

```
{
"id": 15,
"date": "2019-01-01",
"homeTeam": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Super Team"
},
"awayTeam": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Another Team"
}
}
```

Does Lumen support something like that or would I have to build such feature from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

It´s quit easy to replicate this feature.

```php
$game = Game::query()->where('id', $gameId)->with($expandAsArray)->get();
```

You will of cause have to resolved `$expandAsArray` from your query string and split it into an array.